# How do I hide the wizard page title?

Tags: webforms

Webform Version: 6.2.2

I need to hide the wizard page title, but I can not, how it can be done?

I have:

```
identify_01:
  '#type': wizard_page
  '#title': 'Recognise 01'
  '#open': true
```

So I need to hide the "Recognise 01"

I have tried unsuccessfully some combinations like

```
'#title': hidden
'#wizard_page_title': hidden
'#title': hide
'#wizard_page_title': hide
```

and some others

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already editing the *YAML* file, why not try `'#title': ''`

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Webform wizard page uses the `webform-progress-tracker.html.twig template`. I'd recommend you to copy this file in your theme so that you can alter it in a way that fits your needs.

For instance, you could choose to remove any use of `{{ page.title }}` which is the variable containing the wizard page title.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @misterdidi, you gave a good clue. @NKP, if I do that I would lose a reference, my webform is about a 1000 lines in YAML...

I have inspected the css elements, then I went to the webform "settings > CSS/JS" and over there I have added the following CSS code:

```
li.progress-step:nth-child(n) > div:nth-child(n) > div:nth-child(n) {
       display: none;
}
```